# How did I lose 15 reputation points?

Tags: support, reputation

Yesterday, I was browsing and answering questions on Stack Overflow and my reputation points were at 1401 (refer to the screenshot).

[image]

Then after some time, my points were reduced to 1386 and there were no downvotes in my profile (refer to the below screenshot).

[image]

How can this happen without any downvotes?

Or is there any reason for doing this?

Where can I inform about these activities?

Comment: Maybe a question where you had an accepted answer got deleted. Try ticking the "show removed posts" checkbox in your reputation tab, and view your "deleted recent answers".

Comment: There is a little-known feature to [show how your rep is calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation). Maybe that will answer your question?